# Installing a channel drain

Tags: drainage

Is it advisable to convert a single round drain into a channel drain? Will this help lessen the frequency of clogging with leaves or other debris?

Is it just a matter of cutting a wide strip out the concrete?

[image: picture]

Answer (score 1):

Unless it would be a trip hazard (if this is a high-traffic area), I would simply replace the grate with an atrium (raised) style grate.  That style is much more resistant to ponding from debris.  A flat grate simply collects debris against is as water flows, which blocks the subsequent flow.  With a raised grate, the debris collects against the side of the grate at first, but it also floats (usually, anyway, depending on the debris), and the floating allows water to continue flowing beneath.

If you can't remove that grate to replace it, I would recommend using a stainless steel strainer of some sort flipped upside down over the existing grate.  It could be a small sieve with the handle chopped off, or a sink strainer (IDK how big your drain is).  You can use aluminum wire or fishing line to tie the strainer down to the grate.

This would be way less invasive than replacing it with a trench drain.